# Function does not change a var as I thought it would

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple function that increases the number value of one variable by the value of another variable.

( a = 2 ) ( b = 5 ) ( a = a + b )

document.write(a) gives ( 2 ), which is ( a ) but unchanged. I expected to get ( 7 ). What am I doing wrong?

```js
var a = 2;
var b = 5;
function add() {
    a = a + b;
}
document.write(a)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add()">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want the value to update on each click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your document.write(a) write before add function calls so no change. You need to update the element in the inside function
You need to add an HTML element to show your data and use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to set it

```js
var a = 2;
var b = 5;
function add() {
    a = a + b;
   // instead of document.write, find the element that you want to hold your element
   // and set it's inner html to your value
   //this will update the DOM
   document.getElementById("myHeader").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
    <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add()">
   <!-- add an element to hold your result -->
   <h1 id="myHeader">Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: Needs an explanation

Comment: That doesn't explain what you've changed why or what any of this new code does

Answer (score 0):

Make the neccsary changes in the code,

You have to write the `document.write()` at the time you make the function call . 

**In your case :** You wrote it in body so whenever the page load at that time it takes the inital value of `a` and when you make the function call , the value of a get increased but not print .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var a = 2;
            var b = 5;
            function add() {
                a = a + b;
                document.write(a)
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <script></script>
            <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add()">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain why he got this issue instead of just copy pasting code ?

Comment: Explained . ... @jonatjano

Comment: I'm presuming OP wants a to be written above the input, which this won't do

Comment: Yes you've explained the code, but it's still the wrong answer

Comment: No he want to print the 7 instead of 2 . @Liam

Comment: This is what OP asked sir `document.write(a) gives ( 2 ), which is ( a ) but unchanged. I expected to get ( 7 ). What am I doing wrong?` . @Liam

Comment: No, this is the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59983828/542251). Document.write is the wrong thing to use here

Comment: Did you mean wrong thing ? What if OP want to write `document.write()` only ? @Liam

Answer (score 0):

your `document.write(a)` function call is only run the first time the page loads. when you click the button, that only runs the `add()` function but does not rerun `document.write(a)`